# Foreground not visible in real device but visible in emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-image

When I'm setting a foreground for a button it show's fine on Android Studio but when I try it on my phone I cant see the picture selected. Here is a fresh project just to test this:

[image: Left is from phone screenshot, right is from Android Studio]

Something wrong with Android Studio's preferences or its just my phone?

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:foreground="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:foregroundGravity="center" />
```

And here is the Hello World's simple code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `android:foreground` attribute is for a foreground selector (added to a FrameLayout). It's not intended to simply draw an image.

There is no attribute `android:foreground` for a `textView`. and It also doesn't make sense to put a image in foreground on a `textView`. To learn more about the properties and methods for a `textView` follow [Android developer page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

And if you like to add an image on your button then use imageButton.

Comment: I did try them all, button imagebutton etc all the same, seems my phone dosent render right. @shvet-chakra

Comment: I think this answer is no longer true. As of API 23, the `android:foreground` attribute defined in the base `View` class is available to all subclasses, not just `FrameLayout`. The original TextView example shown above should now work as expected, with one caveat. I noticed in my own implementation that setting `android:singleLine="true"` would cause foreground drawables to not be drawn for whatever reason. More info on that here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50974994/5162097

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively I added the image with `android:drawableLeft` (left is ok in my case) and its shown allright. So if anyone is having similar problems `android:drawableLeft` works too.

Comment: didn't you find it at android developer page for textview i posted

Comment: Didnt see it in there but you are right its in the link you provided, so im marking your answer as most helpful.