# android:foreground attribute / setForeground() method does not work with Button elements

Tags: android, button, textview, android-xml

Since [Android 23](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#L5113), the `android:foreground` XML attribute (and corresponding `setForeground()` [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setForeground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))) should be available to all Views, and not just FrameLayout instances as was previously the case.

Yet, for some reason, whenever I create a Button instance which inherits from TextView -> View, I can't seem to get a foreground to show at all.

Here is an example button definition that doesn't work appear to show the foreground:

```
    <Button
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
      android:text="Primary Full Width"
      style="@style/Button.Primary" />
```

And here is the defintion of the `Button.Primary` style:

```
    <style name="Button.Primary" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_primary_background_selector</item>
      <item name="android:foreground">@drawable/button_primary_foreground_selector</item>
      <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.FF.Button</item>
      <item name="android:minHeight">80dp</item>
      <item name="android:height">80dp</item>
      <item name="android:minWidth">200dp</item>
      <item name="android:defaultWidth">288dp</item>
      <item name="android:maxWidth">400dp</item>
      <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
      <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
      <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
      <item name="android:paddingStart">70dp</item>
      <item name="android:paddingEnd">70dp</item>
      <item name="android:stateListAnimator">@null</item>
      <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
      <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
      <item name="android:drawablePadding">10dp</item>
</style>
```

I've confirmed that setting the `foreground` attribute in the style or in the `<Button>` definition does not change anything, the foreground fails to show regardless. The background shows correctly, as does the text, it's just the foreground that's missing.

I've also tried setting the foreground to a solid color instead of a state selector drawable, with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing the style elements one by one and retesting, I narrowed down the issue to the inclusion of the `android:singleLine` attribute in the style.

Removing this attribute made it so any TextViews or Buttons using my style would properly show the foreground drawable as desired. Looking through the implementation of [TextView.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java) where `singleLine` is defined, I'm still struggling to determine how setting this attribute causes foregrounds to be ignored, but I will update this answer if I find out.

I know that use of `singleLine` is deprecated but unfortunately I still need the functionality provided by the combination of the `singleLine` / `ellipsize` attributes which are not available when replacing with `maxLines` usage.

**Edit:** After writing out my answer above, I decided to do some more investigation and uncovered a few more details.

First, I created a custom view that extended from AppCompatButton so I could attempt to re-implement the functionality `singleLine` / `ellipsize` provided (namely, showing text on a single line by replacing newline characters with spaces and then also adding ellipsis if the text ran off the view).

Reading through the [TextView source code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L9057-L9063), I found a section of code that is called when the `singleLine` attribute is set to true:

```
private void applySingleLine(boolean singleLine, boolean applyTransformation,
        boolean changeMaxLines) {
    mSingleLine = singleLine;
    if (singleLine) {
        setLines(1);
        setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
        if (applyTransformation) {
            setTransformationMethod(SingleLineTransformationMethod.getInstance());
        }
    } 
    ...
}
```

So I tried extracting those lines and adding to my own implementation:

```
    private void updateMaxlinesLocally(int maxLines) {
    if (maxLines == 1) {
        Log.d("Button", "max lines was 1, setting to single line equivalent");
        setLines(1);
        setHorizontallyScrolling(true);

 setTransformationMethod(SingleLineTransformationMethod.getInstance());
        // reset any text that may have already been set
        setText(getText());
    } else {
        Log.d("Button", "max lines was  : " + maxLines);
    }
}
```

But when this code ran, I saw the same issue from before where foreground drawables would no longer be visible.

After further testing, I was able to narrow down the issue to the `setHorizontallyScrolling(true)` method call. If I commented just this line out of my custom implementation, I'm able to preserve the `singleLine` / `ellipsize` functionality I had before and foreground drawables show as expected! Narrowing it down to that method still didn't help me figure out the root cause in the TextView base implementation, but if anyone has any details on that, feel free to comment with more information.

Here is my final custom Button class which simply looks at the `maxLines` attribute and simulates the old `singleLine` functionality when `maxLines` is set to 1, avoiding the method call that would prevent foregrounds from showing. In case it's useful...

```
public class Button extends AppCompatButton {

public Button(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context, null, 0);
}

public Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs, 0);
}

public Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public void setMaxLines(int maxLines) {
    super.setMaxLines(maxLines);
    updateMaxlinesLocally(maxLines);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyleAttr) {
    int[] set = {
            android.R.attr.maxLines
    };
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attributeSet, R.styleable.Button);
    int maxLines = a.getInt(R.styleable.Button_android_maxLines, -1);
    a.recycle();
    updateMaxlinesLocally(maxLines);
}

private void updateMaxlinesLocally(int maxLines) {
    if (maxLines == 1) {
        Log.d("Button", "max lines was 1, setting to single line equivalent");
        setLines(1);
        // The act of setting horizontally scrolling to true is what disables foregrounds from
        // showing...
//            setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
        setTransformationMethod(SingleLineTransformationMethod.getInstance());
        // reset any text that may have already been set
        setText(getText());
    } else {
        Log.d("Button", "max lines was  : " + maxLines);
    }
}
```

}

and from attrs.xml:

```
<declare-styleable name="Button">
    <attr name="android:maxLines" format="integer" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Keith `setHorizontallyScrolling(true)`, scrolling makes the foreground disappear. One can easily reproduce the problem.

**But why does horizontal scrolling affect the foreground?**

Setting horizontal (or vertical scroll) tells the `TextView` it contains a larger area than it's layout bounds.

If you print the `scrollX` / `scrollY` values, normally it won't be zeroes but a very big number instead, even if the content is not scrollable by users.

On the other hand, the foreground is designed to scroll with the content, so it's basically drawn starting from `(0, 0)` of the canvas, not the top left corner of the visible content. So it's drawn far far away from the actual view bounds. You can open the `View.java` for the source code of `onDrawForeground` for that.

**What can I do**

- Disable scroll by calling `setHorizontallyScrolling(false)` after setting the `singleline` attribute or anything that implies scrolling. Beware not to get scroll enabled trying to initialize / update the view.
- translate the foreground drawable, e.g. update the bounds from `setBounds` by adding `scrollX` & `scrollY`